# EntityFramework Core 2 Default Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use default values on a couple of my EF models and I'm noticing that either I'm misunderstanding the `HasDefaultValue` behaviour or its not working as it should.

I have the following table and backing model

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[packages]
(
   [Scnumber] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   [PU] INT NOT NULL,
   [State] SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   [Status] [smallint] NOT NULL, 
   [Created] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(), 
   CONSTRAINT [PK_packages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Scnumber] ASC) ON [PRIMARY], 
)

[Table("packages", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Package
{
   [Key]
   [Column(TypeName = "bigint")]
   public long Scnumber { get; set; }

   [Column]
   [Required]
   public int PU { get; set; }

   [Column(TypeName = "smallint")]
   [Required]
   public PackageStatus Status { get; set; }

   [Column(TypeName = "tinyint")]
   public RecordState State { get; set; }

   [Column]
   public DateTime? Created { get; set; }    
}
```

In order to apply default values I've also got the following in my `OnModelCreating()`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Package>(entity =>
{
   entity.Property(r => r.State)
      .HasDefaultValue(RecordState.Active);

   entity.Property(r => r.Created)
      .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
});
```

When I attempt to save a new object I get the following exception:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'State', table
>   'app.dbo.packages'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

This is confusing as if I inspect the object before I save it, it has a default value, but yet I get this exception. I understand the easiest solution would be to simply make sure I set the value of state when I create the object, but this sort of defeats the purpose of `HasDefaultValue`.

-- edit --

When I try to add a new object I do the following

```
var package = new Package { Scnumber = 0123456718, PU = 1001 };

_context.Packages.Add(region);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Nothing about this is out of the norm but fails, but if I run the following it works

```
var package = new Package {Scnumber = 0123456718, PU = 1001, Status = PackageStatus.Rejected, State = RecordState.Staging, Created = DateTime.Now };

_context.Packages.Add(region);
_context.SaveChanges();

public enum PackageStatus : short
{
   New,
   PendingValidation,
   CheckedOut,
   Approved,
   Rejected,
   PendingRender,
   Rendered,
   RenderFailed,
   PendingPrint,
   Printed,
   PrintFailed,
   Cancelled,
   PendingDownload,
   Downloaded,
   DownloadError,
   SystemUpdated, 
}

public enum RecordState : byte
{
    Active,
    Deleted,
    Staging,
}
```

Comment: I'd try adding the Required attribute on State.

Comment: as a workaround, you can set your defaults in Package/Region class: `public RecordState State { get; set; } = RecordState.Active;`. In that case, every object everywhere would work according to the same rules.

Comment: Thats a valid option I didn't consider, but I feel like this is going to drive me mad till I understand whats happening here.

Comment: Can you show `PackageStatus` and `RecordState` enums? Also you've shown the `Package` entity, but the sample code shows `Region`.

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry about that, I've got the same issue with two models and grabbed the wrong one. Thanks for the catch

Comment: There is some discrepancy between the `State` table column type `smallint` and the `enum` type `byte`, which is causing in my case (EF Core 2.0.1) "Invalid Cast Exception". Once I change the enum type to `short` or db column type to `tinyint`, the sample code executes w/o error. Probably you are using older EF Core version?

Answer (score 12):

I have a `.HasDefaultValueSql("((0))")` working in my current project.

Also found `.HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")` and `.HasDefaultValue(3);` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values).

Comment: yeah I'm not sure whats happening as all of these result in nulls for some reason and I can't seem to grok why

Comment: Can I see your insert?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. After updates in `OnModelCreating`
you have to apply migration to database. Write `dotnet ef migrations add defaultValuesAddedToPackage` and then `dotnet ef database update`. This makes default value on column type so you don't need to explicitely set in your new entity or in sql insert. If you write `dotnet ef migrations script` you see code something like `ALTER TABLE [packages] ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR [State];`